# Unable to reach the deployment from the load balancer created in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm new to EKS (but familiar with k8s), and I'm trying to run the my project on EKS.

I ran the my project deployment and the db deployment, and both are running:

```
kubectl get deploy -owide
NAME   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES             SELECTOR
my-app   1/1     1            1           98m   my-app         me/my-app:latest   app=my-app
db     1/1     1            1           16h   db           mariadb:10.4.12    app=db
```

And I created loadbalancer to reach the my-app pods:

```
get svc -owide
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)          AGE    SELECTOR
my-app         LoadBalancer   10.102.XXX.XXX   XXX-XXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   8000:31722/TCP   114m   app=my-app
kubernetes   ClusterIP      10.102.0.1       <none>                                                                    443/TCP          39h    <none>
```

I tried to reach to the website via the external ip created by the loadbalancer (XXX-XXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com), with the port (I tried 80, 8000 and 31722), and I get "the site can't be reached".

Do I miss something?

This is the my-app service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: "8000"
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: my-app
```

This is the my-app yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: REVERSE_PROXY
          value: "true"
        - name: UPLOAD_FOLDER
          value: /var/uploads
        - name: WORKERS
          value: "1"
        image: me/my-app:latest
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: my-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
```

Comment: 1. provide endpoints output. 2.show your deployment yaml.

Comment: @Vitalii I added the deployment yaml. And I don't know what endpoints you talk about

Comment: @Yagel Check the security groups once of your elb

Comment: kubectl get endpoints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest following steps to find root-cause;

1. Check whether laod balancer's XXX-XXX.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com domain is reachable from the host/machine you are trying to access. You can use ping command to check network reachability from your host/machine/laptop/desktop.
2. If step 1 is successfully executed then, Check in default cloudwatch metrics for your load balancer. Please refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#view-metric-data) document about viewing  cloudwatch metrics through AWS web console. You can check any unusable error counts in this metrics.
3. If you did not find any useful information in the Step2 and if you have enabled VPC Flow Logs, then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, what is the problem with network traffic to & from the AWS load balancer. For VPC flow logs information please refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/) document from AWS.